# Eulerlib in python 2.7.13

Tags: python, attributeerror

After solving this problem link https://projecteuler.net/problem=27, I found another solution to the problem :

```
import itertools , eulerlib 
def compute():
    ans = max(((a, b) for a in range(-999, 1000) for b in range(2, 1000)),
        key=count_consecutive_primes)
    return str(ans[0] * ans[1])

def count_consecutive_primes(ab):
    a, b = ab
    for i in itertools.count():
        n = i * i + i * a + b
        if not is_prime(n):
            return i
isprimecache = eulerlib.list_primality(1000)

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 0:
       return False
    elif n < len(isprimecache):
        return isprimecache[n]
    else:
        return eulerlib.is_prime(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(compute())
```

And when i run this i get this message Error: 
    AttributeError :'module' object has no attribute 'list_primality'.
    In fact i have already installed euerlib

Comment: Are you sure you have the most recent version of `eulerlib`? Try doing `pip install --upgrade eulerlib` and then trying again.

Comment: i get this message : You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command .